# Get the first letter of each word preceded by space or dot

Tags: javascript

I need to take the first letter of each word in a string when preceded by `space` or `.`

Example 1: `Hello World I'm a web.dev from.japan.com cool`

Needed solution 1 : `HWIAW.DF.J.CC`

Example 2: `Hello World This   is awesome`

Needed solution 2 : `HWTIA`

EDIT : (I wasn't very clear)

All I could came up with is this :

```
const sentence = "Hello World I'm a web.dev from.japan.com cool";
sentence.split(/[\s.]+/).map((n) => n[0]).join("").toUpperCase();
```

Gives me the result : `HWIAWDFJCC`, but I need to maintain the dots too.

But this doesn't solve my case.

Comment: for one, you're not assigning your maps to a variable. `myMap = sentence.split(".").map((n) => n[0]).join(".");`

Comment: Yes, I was just mentioning what approach I tried to use to cut and join the parts

Comment: We need to see the entire picture, a minimal reproducible example, in order to help. The problem could be caused by something you're not showing us.

Comment: @user1599011 all the code is there, it is just not a snipplet....

Comment: I edited my question, thank you

Comment: `"Hello World I'm a web.dev from.japan.com cool".replace(/(^.|\..|\s+.)[^\s\.]+/g, '$1').replace(/\s/g, '').toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine those 2 actions in one chained method - first removing extra spaces, then splitting by space, and finally splitting by period.

```js
let ex1="Hello World I'm a web.dev from.japan.com cool"
//Needed solution 1 : HWIAW.DF.J.CC

let ex2= "Hello World This   is awesome";
//Needed solution 2 : HWTIA

const trans = (str) => str.replace(/  +/g, ' ').split(' ').map(s => s.split('.').map(t => t[0]).join('.')).join('').toUpperCase() ;
console.log(trans(ex1));
console.log(trans(ex2));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = "Hello World This   is awesome"

let split = (s) => s.split(" ") //splitting based on space
  .filter((w) => w !== "") //filtering empty string created by consecutive spaces
  .map((word) => word.split('.') //splttting based on .
    .map((spl) => spl[0].toUpperCase()) //returning first uppercase letter
    .join('.')) //joining splitted . array
  .join("") //final join

console.log(split(s));
console.log(split("Hello World I'm a web.dev from.japan.com cool"));
```

Comment: Edited it so I could see both example strings running

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
let sentence = "   Hello World    I'm a web.dev from.japan.com cool"
let chunks = sentence.trim().split(/[\s]+/g);
let result = '';

chunks.forEach(str => {
  if (str.includes('.')) {
    let word = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i] === '.') {
        result += word[0];
        word = "";
        result += str[i];
      } else {
        word += str[i];
      }
    }
    result += word[0];
  } else {
    result += str[0];
  }
});


result = result.toUpperCase();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a working version.

```js
let str1 = "Hello World I'm a web.dev from.japan.com cool";
let str2 = "Hello World This   is awesome";

function getFirstLetters(parameter) {
    const array = [];
    const str = parameter.replaceAll('.', ' ');
    let firstLetters = "";

    array.push(str.split(" "));
    array.forEach(item => {
        for (let i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
            firstLetters += item[i].charAt(0);
        }
    });

    return firstLetters.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(getFirstLetters(str1));
console.log(getFirstLetters(str2));
```